# Inno Setup sub-options/sub-components for different setup types (server/client)

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm trying to prepare a setup for my app with server and client installation type.
Server type is easy with some code, but Client installation have many options too.
I'm trying to have a page with type selection and if the user select client installation, many other chooses.
Is it possible?

Example:

- Server

  - (no option)
- Client

  - sub option A or
  - sub option B

Comment: Yes it is possible. What problem do you have with implementing it? What is your script for "server type" selection? Do you use Components page?

Comment: i don't have already the script for server installation. i'm designing the structure of installer first. Server type has only sql db installation. Client has 2 options depending to ini file value instead. i don't know how to use components page for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather broad. But if I understand correctly what you need, you can make use of the standard Inno Setup [Types](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=typessection) – [Components](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection) – [Tasks](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection) system:

```
[Types]
Name: server; Description: "Server";
Name: client; Description: "Client";

[Components]
; The "descriptions" are not visible in this setup
Name: server; Description: "Server"; Types: server;
Name: client; Description: "Client"; Types: client;

[Tasks]
Name: client1; Description: "Client feature 1"; Components: client;
Name: client2; Description: "Client feature 2"; Components: client;

[Files]
Source: "Server.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: server;
Source: "ClientFeature1.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Tasks: client1;
Source: "ClientFeature2.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Tasks: client2;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything in one place, you can make use of parent components:

```
[Types]
Name: custom; Description: "Custom"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: server; Description: "Server"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: client; Description: "Client"; Flags: exclusive
Name: client\feature1; Description: "Feature 1"
Name: client\feature2; Description: "Feature 2"
```

(Whichever one you put `Types: custom` on is selected by default.)

You can then condition things on `Components: client` for all clients, or `Components: client\feature1` for only when feature 1 is selected, etc.

There are some other variations depending on whether the client features are mutually exclusive or not.